# Obtaining a Distinct of a Column and Max and Min of two different columns and returning it as a single record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with several columns and rows and I have performed some mathematical calculations on the table and returned them as a different table using the following SQL View

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[XYZ]
AS
with numbered as
(
    select 
        id, 
        product,  
        term, 
        bid, 
        offer, 
        termid,
        productid, 
        bidVolume,
        offerVolume, 
        row_number() OVER (Partition BY Product ORDER BY termid ) i
    from  dbo.abc
)

select 
    Row_number() over(order by r1.i)  as Id, 
    r1.Product + '/' + r2.Product as Market, 
    r1.term as Term, 
    r1.Bid - r2.Offer [Bid], 
    r1.Offer - r2.Bid [Offer]
from numbered r1 
join numbered r2 
    on   r1.Product != r2.Product 
    and r1.termid = r2.termid  
    and r1.term = r2.term 
    and r1.ProductID < r2.ProductID 
    and r1.Product Not like '%/%' 
    and r2.Product not like '%/%'

GO
```

I got the following results

**Table 1:**

```
Id Market Term Bid Offer
1   A/B    Jan14  NULL NULL
2   A/B    jan14  NULL 20
3   A/B    Jan14  10  NULL
4   A/B    Jan14  5   10
5   X/Z    Mar14  10  12
6   X/Z    Mar14   8  9
```

From the Above results I am trying to write a query which returns one row for each Market and Term with highest bid and lowest offer something like the follwing

**Table 2:**

```
Id Market Term    Bid Offer
 1   A/B    Jan14  10 10
 2   X/Z    Mar14  10  9
```

PS: From above results we can see that Bid and Offer with Id=1 are coming from two different records from original Table which highest and lowest respectively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a simple `group by`:

```
select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as id,
       market, term, max(bid) as Bid, min(offer) as offer
from XYZ
group by market, term;
```